# Multi-Dimensional Array: How to build a recursive count()

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
membership = array(5) { 
 [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(21) "Group A" [1]=> string(9) "10/1/2011" [2]=> string(9) "3/31/2012" [3]=> string(8) "00004130" } 
 [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(22) "Group B" [1]=> string(8) "4/1/2011" [2]=> string(9) "9/30/2011" [3]=> string(8) "00005005" } 
 [2]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(22) "Group A" [1]=> string(9) "10/1/2010" [2]=> string(9) "3/31/2011" [3]=> string(8) "00004130" } 
 [3]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(22) "Group B" [1]=> string(8) "4/1/2010" [2]=> string(9) "9/30/2010" [3]=> string(8) "00005005" }  
 [4]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(22) "Group B" [1]=> string(8) "10/1/2010" [2]=> string(9) "3/31/2011" [3]=> string(8) "00005005" }  
}
```

***I need to discover which group is in the membership array and how many times it appears.***

PHP's **count()** does not have recursive capability, but it's output would be ideal if it did (i.e. ['Group A'] => 2  ['Group B'] => 3 ).

I thought about using the array_diff_uassoc() but, I'm just not sure.  So I thought it wise to ask for some help before I wander aimlessly down the wrong path.  I am sure there is more than one way, but I always find very interesting coding concepts on SO.

I'm running php 5.3.5 Thank you in advance for your suggestions and help.

Comment: `PHP's count() does not have recursive capability` huh? Look into manual on `count's` 2nd argument. Anyway it wont do what You want anyway, just simply use `foreach` and that's it.

Comment: does the data come from a db?

Comment: Since they're all at the same depth, why do you need it to be recursive? Potential future reuse?

Comment: Re: @Bartosz and those who up count his comment; he answered his own comment with "anyway, it won't do what you want anyway.."  PHP's count() only adds the number of items within a multi-dimensional array, it does not list the name and how often it shows the way it does on a single level array.  It would be more beneficial to up count either of the two answers that were given that DO answer the post accurately.  As oftentimes happens on SO, some like to respond right away but not with the care and knowledge of others.  Please show your recognition where it's best deserved - keeping SO the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick with minimal code:

```
$memberships = array(); // Your multi-dimensional array

foreach($memberships as $membership)
{
   $count[$membership[0]]++;
}

var_dump($count)
```

Sorry for the late post BTW, I wanted to [test it](http://ideone.com/UXEb9) and make sure it would work as expected.

Output is:

```
array(2) {
  ["Group A"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Group B"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Nice, clean, simple.  Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: And thanks for the Ideone.com test results!  I've seen this site coming up more in my searches.  It looks interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I only started using it recently. It's very handy for testing small snippets of code to make sure a solution will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

given what you have, this is it. doesn't even need to be recursive since your array is just 2D

```
<?php
$membership = array( 
    array("Group A","10/1/2011","3/31/2012","00004130" ),
    array("Group B","4/1/2011","9/30/2011","00005005" ), 
    array("Group A","10/1/2010","3/31/2011","00004130" ), 
    array("Group B","4/1/2010","9/30/2010","00005005" ),  
    array("Group B","10/1/2010","3/31/2011","00005005" )  
);

//initialize array for safety
$count = array();

//loop through each item
foreach($membership as $row){

    //check if group exists in count array
    $group = $row[0];
    $groupExists = array_key_exists($group,$count);

    if($groupExists){
        //if we've crossed paths before, just add 1
        $count[$group]++;
    } else {
        //otherwise, let's start with 1
        $count[$group]=1;
    }
}

var_dump($count);

//output dump should look like 
array(2) {
  ["Group A"]=> int(2)
  ["Group B"]=> int(3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Joseph.  Cillosis was just simpler, but I do appreciate the lesson in your post.  Again, Thank you!